# Text centering in math mode

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, split

I wonder whether (in math mode) it is possible to split somehow what is given by following picture:

[image: Splitting]

The limit needs to stay centered, but the text "(P1)" is supposed to be flushed to the left.

Comment: Should (P1) be some kind of numeration?

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Comment: (P1) is just text, not numeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should do what you want:

```
.................
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign}
  &\rlap{(P1)} &\lim_{s\to+\infty}\frac{f(s}{s}&=+\infty &
\end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With this code, \text{P1} is flushed to the left, but the limit is flushed to the right :( Limit should be centered.

Comment: To centre the limit you could add "&\phantom{\text{(P1)}}" after "+\infty". Doesn't feel like the most elegant solution, but it'd work.

Comment: Bas copy-paste. I've fixed it: there was one missing `&`.

Comment: @MartinKaisler: To ensure a perfect centring of the equation, you can use `\rlap{(P1)}` in the place of `\text{(P1)}`.

Comment: Very good, that's better than my suggestion.